# tf.TensorArray allow reading from an unwritten index?

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to use TensorArrays in a nested while loop and I faced issues when combining read and write on a particular TensorArray index.

I trying investigating the error and it seems TensorFlow throws an error when I trying reading from an unwritten index and then subsequently write to that index.

"InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): TensorArray TensorArray_0: Could not write to TensorArray index 5 because it has already been read."

I tried looking for solutions and found this issue.
https://git.codingcafe.org/Mirrors/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/06bd05e0018969b9c0696233ceb7fa881e50210c

To better frame this question, I simplified my code in this snippet.

```py
def loop_body1(i, x):
    x = tf.cond(tf.equal(i, 0), lambda: x.write(i+1, 10), lambda: x.write(i+1, 1 + x.read(i-1)))
    i = tf.add(i, 1)
    return i, x

num_iterations = 5
iteration_num1 = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)

array = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=1, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=False)         # dynamic size
loop_condition1 = lambda iteration_num1, predictions: tf.less(iteration_num1, num_iterations)

# First loop - same as previous cell
_, array = tf.while_loop(loop_condition1, loop_body1, [iteration_num1, array])

array = array.write(tf.constant(0), 100)
loop_op1 = array.stack()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
outputs = sess.run(loop_op1)
print(outputs)
```

The line

array = array.write(tf.constant(0), 100)

throws an error because I write to index 0 after having read from index 0 in the loop body.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't setting `clear_after_read=False` in the constructor help?

Comment: clear_after_read is set to False here as well which enables multiple reads. But the problem here is that the TensorArray doesn't have any initial values so reading an index before writing into it causes problems.
The situation arises when I have a tf.cond which reads a value from the TensorArray for the conditional check but then if the condition is true, it writes into that index.